# Problems intalling Mothur 39.5 (no makefile found)

Tags: software-installation

I am new to both UBUNTU and Mothur. I am trying to install the 39.5 Mothur version that I have downloaded from https://github.com/mothur/mothur/releases (Mothur.linux_64.zip). I have followed the installation pipeline provided by Mothur:

```
 mkdir mothur
 cd mothur
 unzip ../Mothur.source.zip
 make
```

But I get this error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I went into the files and I can't find any makefiles (Blast, CatchAllCmdL.exe, LICENSE, mothur, uchime, vsearch. I could try using:

```
Sudo apt install mothur
```

but, it only installs the previous version.If somebody could give a hand with this!.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to compile under linux, always get the .tar.gz version. After uncompressing it (tar xvzf file.tar.gz), you should go inside the extrated directory then call `make`.

Comment: You have to download the source files (Source code (zip or tar.gz)) from here: https://github.com/mothur/mothur/releases

Comment: I downloaded the file and extracted in the mothur file after which I tried    make    and got this: source/mothur.h:21:52: fatal error: boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:100: recipe for target 'source/progress.o' failed
make: *** [source/progress.o] Error 1

Comment: @Cota Do you want to compile Mothur from source code? Your recent comment suggests you do, but as [RoVo's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021931) and [my](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021930/22949) answers explain, it's probably unnecessary. The error you got while trying to build it looks like it can be solved by installing packages that provide libraries and header files (maybe `libboost-all-dev`, but you may be able to install *way* less and have it work). But do you even need to compile it? *If so*, please **[edit]** to explain, and also give details about what you've done and the complete output.

Comment: I saw both of your answer a bit later.. but tried @RoVo's and worked out great. Thanks both o f you!

Comment: No problem--I'm glad the problem is solved. Since [RoVo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021931/22949) was what most directly helped you solve the problem, [you may want to accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) if you are not still looking for more answers. (Accepting an answer won't actually keep people from posting more answers, but it will communicate that you consider the problem solved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build `mothur` from source.
[Mothur.linux_64.zip](https://github.com/mothur/mothur/releases/download/v1.39.5/Mothur.linux_64.zip) is ready to execute.

```
$ wget https://github.com/mothur/mothur/releases/download/v1.39.5/Mothur.linux_64.zip
$ unzip Mothur.linux_64.zip
$ cd mothur
$ ./mothur
```

gives this:

> mothur v.1.39.5
>   Last updated: 3/20/2017
>   [...]
>   mothur >

Answer (score 1):

`Mothur.linux_64.zip` contains an executable that is already compiled. You don't have to build it; you can just run it. If you have `cd`ed to the unpacked `mothur` directory that contains the file that is also called `mothur`, you can simply run the command:

```
./mothur
```

You may want to put unpack the `mothur` directory (or move the unpacked directory) wherever you like, then put a symbolic link to that `mothur` executable somewhere in your `PATH`.

If you're able to run the program but then want information on how to use it, you can type `help()` into the prompt it gives you, which lists all available commands as well as links for documentation.

**If you actually want to compile it from source code** then you will have to download the source code, which as [pim says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021923/problems-intalling-mothur-39-5-no-makefile-found#comment1659532_1021923) you can do by getting the `.tar.gz` file labeled "Source code" on [the download page](https://github.com/mothur/mothur/releases). But based on what you have asked, I have no reason to think you actually need or want that. With what you have, you should be able to run the program; it is already compiled for you, so you don't need to compile it first.

Comment: +1 because you were 5 secs faster than me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or simply install it from the [package repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mothur) (also available for [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/de/stretch/mothur)):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mothur
```